# Google Analytics Pagviews

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, google-analytics

I have an issue with my GA tracking on a wordpress beverage site using monster insights.  On the site there is a page which displays 6 flavors.  When a user goes to /flavors it tracks the pageview correctly.  There are 6 individual flavors on the page that users can click to get more detail and share via social media etc...The problem is when users click a flavor the hash tag in the URL updates to that appropriate flavor and multiple pageviews are sent.  This compounds every time a new flavor is clicked.  When flavor 1 is clicked it sends one pageview,  when flavor two is selected it sends 2 pageviews, flavor three it sends three and so on.  Here's my code I'm using.  I'm fairly new to analytics so any insight would help.  The url for the page is https://www.shastasparklingwater.com/flavors/

```
    $j(window.location.hash).collapse('show');
$j('a[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function () {
    var href = $j(this).attr('href');
    $j('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function (href) {
        window.location.hash = this.id;
        var page = '/flavors/' + window.location.hash;
        __gaTracker('set', 'page', page);
        __gaTracker('send', 'pageview', page);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are adding an event listener to each of the individual flavors each time that a flavor is clicked, which is why your see the incremental page views being sent.  Try this code:

```html
$j(window.location.hash).collapse('show');
var href = $j(this).attr('href');
$j('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function (href) {
  window.location.hash = this.id;
  var page = '/flavors/' + window.location.hash;
  __gaTracker('set', 'page', page);
  __gaTracker('send', 'pageview', page);
});
```